# nginx is downloading some files instead of executing them

Tags: php, nginx

For some reason, my nginx installation is running some `.php` files properly, while doesn't.

I have some files:

- upload.php, sig.php, popup.php - executes and works.
- asdfsda.php - doesn't work, when I visit it, the file downloads.
- **(SOLVED by clearing browser cache)** visiting my domain - downloads my index.html file with the name "download", when I visit mydoma.in/index.html, I can see my index file properly.

I have no idea what could cause this issue.

I tried:

- reinstalling PHP5-FPM
- restarting the server
- restarting nginx/php5-fpm services
- chmod files to 777

Related nginx config part:

```
root /boot/www;

index index.html index.php;

server_name - my domain here -;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /upload.php {
    include php5.conf;
}

location /asdfsda.php {
    include php5.conf;
}

location /popup.php {
    include php5.conf;
}

location /sig.php {
    include php5.conf;
}
```

php5.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
```

This issue started today, I didn't change anything in my config files recently.
It worked fine yesterday.

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

UPDATE: If I change the name of `asdfsda.php` file that doesn't execute to something else, it actually does execute. For example, I renamed it to `d.php` and changed the config entry from `asdfsda` to `d` and it executed.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this?

```
location ~ ^/(upload|asdfsda|popup|sig)\.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Because I want php for just some specific files, my site is a file uploading site and I'm afraid people will somehow discover an exploit to run their php code from their uploaded files, they could upload some "file manager" (or, "shell") of any kind and ruin my site.